# Is XOR equal to XNOR when odd number of inputs are considered?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

I was attempting a question which said that you can convert a Full Adder into a Full Subtractor with using just one inverter. Later I researched on this XOR and found that that for even no. of inputs it is the invert of XNOR and for odd number of inputs it is equal to XNOR. Is it true? 
Also Can we say that the XOR gate gives true or 1 value only when there are odd numbers of 1 in the input.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of a a XOR gate with multiple inputs needs to be defined, it is not just a simple extension of the two-input XOR gate. As always with definitions it is possible to have different, even contradicting, ones.

In my opinion [this definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/XOR.html) seems to be useful:

> For multiple arguments, XOR is defined to be true if an odd number of
>   its arguments are true, and false otherwise. This definition is quite
>   common in computer science, where XOR is usually thought of as
>   addition modulo 2. In this context, it arises in polynomial algebra
>   modulo 2, arithmetic circuits with a full adder, and in parity
>   generating or checking. While this means that the multiargument "XOR"
>   can no longer be thought of as "the exclusive OR" operation, this form
>   is rarely used in mathematical logic and so does not cause very much
>   confusion.

The XNOR would just be the inverse of the XOR.

Comment: What other definition would there be?  XOR is associative so that's the natural result.

Comment: There is already an answer with a different definition.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand your first question. You said both are odd, yet one is inverted and one is same?

For the second question, yes. XOR is true when there's an odd number of 1s in the input.

Comment: No, XOR is true when there is exactly one 1 in the inputs.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen You may be talking about 2-input XOR, I'm speaking generally. For any N-input XOR the output is true when an odd number of inputs is true.

Comment: Hmmm, I'll lift my -1 on your answer: the world doen't agree on this point.

Answer (score 0):

The output of an 2-input XOR is clearly defined. An XNOR is simply an XOR with an inverter after it.

But now for multiple inputs...

As far as I can find, for the rectangular (IEC) symbol, the definition is that the output is 1 when *exactly one input is 1*, otherwise it is 0. The 'rectangular' symbol shows this by stating "=1".

[image]

For the classic (US) symbol the behaviour for more than 2 inputs is not defined. Sometimes this "=1" is even used in the classic symbol, in which case it has the same behaviour as the rectangular symbol.

[image]

But the only 3-input XOR chip that I found ([74LVC1G386](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74LVC1G386.pdf)) implements the funtion ( A xor ( B xor C )): the output is 1 for any odd number of inputs that are 1.

Answer (score 0):

XOR is 1 for odd no. 1's in inputs while XNOR is 1 for even no. of 0's.

So, XOR(1, 1, 1) = 1 and XNOR(1, 1, 1) = 1

But XOR(1, 1) = 0 and XNOR(1, 1) = 1